# Does anyone know about sensible tableview?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Have anyone used and can recommend to me a tool called sensible tableview for iPhone development? I have been hearing a lot about it lately so I've been wondering if anyone has any experience with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I bought it and have found it worthwhile. The customer support is excellent. There are still some bugs on the iPad, but they're working with me to fix them very rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

I have also purchased it, and can recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Look around in google, and [this page](http://www.sensiblecocoa.com/) is the only page I see. I didn't here anything about sensible TableView before:(